# Conditional association on query

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I have two models:

```
class Table extends Eloquent {
    protected $table = 'tables';

    public function sessions() {
        return $this->hasMany('Sessions');
    }
}

class Sessions extends \Eloquent {
    protected $table = 'sessions';

    public function table() {
        return $this->belongsTo('Table');
    }
}
```

(I call it Sessions instead of Session because Laravel was having trouble confusing classes).

Table refers to an actual diner table and a session is just someone or some group using it.
So, I come to the table, seat down, start a session, eat, pay, close session and leave. You then come and sit on the very same table, which corresponds to a new session.

Now, this is how I'm querying my table:

```
$table = Table::where('id', '=', $id)->with('sessions')->first();
```

However, my table comes with all it's related sessions. How should I go about querying:

-Returns table + single session if the table has a session which is open(Session.closed_at = '0000-00-00 00:00:00').
-Returns table only with no associated records if it has no open sessions.

How should I go about  building this very same query in my Controller and in my model(such as Table::getWithSessions($id)).

Thanks.

Addendum:
Soon I will have a quite more complex relationship:
A table has many sessions(which only one matters, the active one), which has many cards(each person may get their individual cards), which can have many orders. Order are a join between a card and a item, which points to an product or many of them(for example, a kit with several different beers).

I would appreciate any insight on how to build this kind of relationship with eloquent and get all playing nicely(such as being able to query for the tables and get all orders for all cards related to the current session).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can filter the models to eager load by using a closure in `with()` to define your conditions. Also you can use `find()` instead of `where('id',... ->first()`:

```
$table = Table::with(['sessions' => function($q){
    $q->where('closed_at', '0000-00-00 00:00:00');
}])->find($id);
```

**Note** that because the normally relationship returns a collection, it will still return one. So when accessing the session you need to use: `$table->sessions->first()` to get the current one.

---

To get tables without an open session, simply use `whereDoesntHave`:

```
$tables = Table::whereDoesntHave('sessions', function($q){
    $q->where('closed_at', '0000-00-00 00:00:00');
})->get();
```

### Edit

For a call like `Table::getWithSessions($id)` you have two options.

#### 1. static method

Create a static method like this:

```
public static function getWithSessions($id){
    return static::with(['sessions' => function($q){
        $q->where('closed_at', '0000-00-00 00:00:00');
    }])->find($id);
}
```

#### 2. Use [scopes](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/eloquent#query-scopes)

With a scope you can do something like:

```
Table::withOpenSessions()->find($id);
```

This is the scope method:

```
public function scopeWithOpenSessions($query){
    return $query->with(['sessions' => function($q){
        $q->where('closed_at', '0000-00-00 00:00:00');
    }]);
}
```

Comment: I hope this is enough to get you on the right track and helps you solve your other problems. If you still need help, just leave a comment :)

Comment: Thanks, that helped me a lot and definitely put me on track. How should I go about implementing a static model method such as Table::getWithSessions($id)? Would instantiating a new table model inside the method and then doing the query be the correct way?

Comment: Yes, or directly call `static::with()` or use a scope. See my updated answer for more details.